# Call a function on click event in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to declare a function inside a component (typescript) and call it on a click event in Angular 2?
Following is the code for the same functionality in Angular 1 for which I require Angular 2 code:

```html
<button ng-click="myFunc()"></button>
```

//controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($cope) {
    $scope.myFunc= {
        console.log("function called");
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Why did you tag `angular2` if this is an `Angular 1` app?

Comment: Scant description, structurally wrong sentences, ugly code. all of the result in wrong understanding. people this this is an Angular1 question!

Comment: Whatever I have written in code I want do same in angular2.

Comment: Old post, but I recommend looking at the "tour of Heros" from the angular 2 documentation.

Comment: Is it Angular 1 or Angular 2? It should've been specified

Comment: Maybe it's a language issue.  The question is perfectly clear to me: "Here's how I do it in Angular 1.  How do I do the equivalent in Angular 2?"  No wonder frameworks are so bad.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Component code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public items: Array<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
  }

  public open(event, item) {
    alert('Open ' + item);
  }

}
```

View:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      <span>My App</span>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="open($event, item)">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see in the code, I'm declaring the click handler like this `(click)="open($event, item)"` and sending both the event and the item (declared in the `*ngFor`) to the `open()` method (declared in the component code).

If you just want to show the item and you don't need to get info from the event, you can just do `(click)="open(item)"` and modify the `open` method like this `public open(item) { ... }`

Comment: how about disappear this menu after logoff? my databootstrapperpage using menu like this and every other push page has their own but after logoff and goto login page this menu unexpected appeared so after click disappeared but icant handle this.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi could you please create a **[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xe4ssu)** with your issue so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 78):

Exact transfer to **Angular2+** is as below:

```html
<button (click)="myFunc()"></button>
```

also in your component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"button.html" //this is the component which has the above button html
})

export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  myFunc(){
    console.log("function called");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

https://angular.io/guide/user-input  -  there's a simple example .

Comment: Referring to original documentations is a better approach since the is a great chance of learning more.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me: :)

```html
<button (click)="updatePendingApprovals(''+pendingApproval.personId, ''+pendingApproval.personId)">Approve</button>
```

```js
updatePendingApprovals(planId: string, participantId: string) : void {
  alert('PlanId:' + planId + '    ParticipantId:' + participantId);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The line in your controller code, which reads `$scope.myFunc={` should be `$scope.myFunc = function() {` the `function()` part is important to indicate, it is a function!

The updated controller code would be

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($cope){
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
    console.log("function called");
  };
}]);
```