# Jquery and @media in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

## Hello there!

I have an Angular project, where i'm working with HTML, CSS and Jquery.
I have a paragraph set with "display: none", and I want it to appear only when the user click a "button" tag. The thing is, the CSS is inside a @media annotation. And I can't put it inside the Paragraph tag like "style=@media all and...." as the HTML file does not compile with the annotation. It has to be inside a specific CSS document. Thanks to that, I cannot use Jquery to override the display of the Paragraph tag.

This is how it goes:

HTML:

```
<p id="two">
    The history of ...</p>
```

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 580px) {

   p#two
   {
       display: none;
   }

}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p#one button").click(function(){
      $("p#two").attr("style", "display: normal")
    });
});
```

I also tried a Jquery like:

```
    $("p#one button").click(function(){
      $("p#two").css({"display" : "normal"});
    });
```

or

```
$("p#one button").click(function(){
      $("p#two").css({
        display : 'normal'});
    });
```

But nothing seems to override the "display: none". 
What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: [Please read this first.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1264804) You should not be manipulating the DOM with jQuery in an Angular app.

Comment: Back on topic, `normal` isn't a valid value for `display`. Try `block`.

Comment: The logic you are attempting to do should be related to an `ng-click` on the button that changes a state some where in the angular app, which is used to determine if the other element(s) are displayed or not, either with an `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

Comment: @Taplar, that would be in AngularJS.

Comment: AngularJS !== Angular.

Comment: Ok, I'm missing something.  What are you associating with 'Angular' if not Angular 1 or Angular 2?

Comment: There is no Angular 1. There's AngularJS, and there's the entirely revised framework simply called Angular, which started with version 2. `ngShow` and `ngHide` don't exist in Angular.

Comment: Ok, so quick search looks like it would be something like `(click)="function"`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211730/call-a-function-on-click-event-in-angular-2#40211968  The same concept applies though.  This logic should be done with the angular bindings and not jQuery

Comment: And related to the ngShow/ngHide in Anguar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't like to mix css properties with javascript unless it's really really really necessary.

You can add a class for `p#two` that overrides the `display: none` property and toggle that class `on` on click.

```
@media all and (max-width: 580px) {
   p#two { display: none; }
   p#two.show { display: initial; } // "normal" is not a valid value for display
}
```

Then, on your click event handler, you add the class:

```
document.getElementById('two').classList.add('show')
```

Note that `normal` is not a valid option for `display` and also that both jquery and angular can handle showing element with their own methods like `$('#p').show()` of the `ng-if` directive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple way to resolve this problem:

```
@media all and (max-width: 580px) {

    p.hidden-class {
       display: none;
    }

    p.visible-class {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

And toggle your class with ngClass.