# How to pass parameters to a typescript function from html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am fetching my `users` in the form of a JSONArray and I want to show the data of each user when clicked on their names. but I am not able to pass the `user.id` into the function.

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let user of users" >
        <button (onclick)="getdata(user.id)" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{user.name}}</button>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: Angular uses event names for binding. docs: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-events

Comment: Sidenote: you don't have to use `ng-container` you can put the `*ngFor` directive directly on your `button` element.

Comment: Too many answer can be found on the stackoverflow for similar questions. For example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211730/call-a-function-on-click-event-in-angular-2 is related to button usage on angular.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try the same with using **only click() instead on onclick()**

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let user of users" >
    <button (click)="getdata(user.id)" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{user.name}}</button>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its angular use `(click)` instead of `(onclick)`

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
  <button (click)="getdata(user.id)" mat-raised-button color="primary">
    {{ user.name }}
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

```js
getdata(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let user of users" >
    <button (click)="getdata(user.id)" mat-raised-button color="primary">{{user.name}}</button>
</ng-container>
```